# Test if table cell content is text or textarea using jquery

Tags: jquery

I wan to find out where my table cell contain text box, textarea or just a text. Is there a way to get element and test its type in jQuery?

```
$('tr td').each(function() {
  if(textBox or textArea) {
    //doA();
  } else {
    //doB();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know if `this` contains a "text box" (e.g., inside the `each`):

```
if ($(this).find("input[type=text]").length) {
    // Yes, at least one
}
```

Although `input` with no `type` is also a text box, so you might want to be more thorough (the DOM `type` property will be `"text"` even if the `input` element has no `type` attribute):

```
if ($(this).find("input").filter(function() {
        return this.type === "text";
    }).length) {
    // Yes, at least one
}
```

(You'll want to decide how to handle HTML5 `type="number"` and such.)

`textarea` is simpler:

```
if ($(this).find("textarea").length) {
    // Yes, at least one
}
```

Comment: Those two can be combined into a single selector: `find('input[type=text], textarea')`... In fact, in the OP's case I think `find(':input')` will suffice too (although it includes selects and buttons as well).

Comment: @raina77ow: `:input` would also match checkboxes and radio buttons and buttons... It also wasn't clear to me that the OP didn't want to do different things for text boxes and `textarea`s...

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the input and textarea and check it by using length property if that exists or not:

```
$('tr td').each(function() {
  if($(this).find('input[type="text"],textarea').length) {
    //doA();
  } else {
    //doB();
  }
});
```